# Proving a sequence is Cauchy given some qualities about the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I've got a sequence $x_n$ such that I've proved $b\leq x_n \leq c$, and $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\leq \frac{4}{9}|x_n-x_{n-1}|$

However I'm not very familiar with Cauchy sequences, so I don't know how to exactly prove it's Cauchy. I've gotten so far:

Let $m,n>0$. Then $m=n+a$. So
\begin{align*}
|x_m-x_n| &= |x_{n+a}-x_n|\\
&= |(x_{n+a}-x_{n+a-1})+(x_{n+a-1}-x_{n+a-2})+\ ...\ +(x_{n+1}-x_n)|\\
&\leq a|x_n-x_{n-1}|
\end{align*}

I know I'm close, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

EDIT:
\begin{align*}
|x_m-x_n| &= |x_{n+a}-x_n|\\
&= |(x_{n+a}-x_{n+a-1})+(x_{n+a-1}-x_{n+a-2})+\ ...\ +(x_{n+1}-x_n)|\\
&\leq \Sigma_{i=1}^{i=a}(\frac{4}{9})^i * |x_{n}-x_{n-1}|\\
&\leq (c-b)\frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{1-(4/9)^a}{5/9}\\
&\leq \frac{4}{5}(c-b)(1-(\frac{4}{9})^a)
\end{align*}

But now I'm not sure how to say it's Cauchy.

EDIT 2:

$$\frac{4}{5}(c-b)(1-(\frac{4}{9})^a) \leq \frac{4}{5}(c-b)$$

So let $n_0 = \epsilon * \frac{5}{4(c-b)}$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$,   $|x_m-x_n|<\epsilon$ whenever $m,n > \frac{5}{2}\epsilon$.

Comment: Hint: geometric series of ratio $4/9$.

Comment: Ah! I Think I get it. I'll get a sum from 1 to a of $\frac{4}{9}|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ which simplifies to (4/9) * ((4/9)^a -1) / ((4/9) - 1) |x_n - x_(n-1)| correct?

Comment: I can't read your comment, but the idea is that $|x_{k}-x_{k-1}|\leq (4/9)^{k-1}|x_1-x_0|$ by induction. And then you can use that after you second equality to get a sharper estimate.

Comment: Haha, sorry. Forgot to use tex for a bit. I just finished up the problem (I think) so do you think you could do a quick look-over to see if I've got any flaws in my logic / reasoning?

Comment: It does not work, because your upper bound does not tend to $0$ when $a$ tends to $\infty$. You need to go all the way down to $|x_1-x_0|$ like I mentioned in my previous comment. And you will not need these $b, c$.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHH I was trying to see the flaw in my logic before I went down to $|x_1-x_0|%

Now I see it. Thanks!

Comment: What about the logarithm or square root functions? Isn't $|x_{n+1}-x+n| \leq |x_n - x_{n-1}|$ but they are not Cauchy sequences as they don't have upper bounds?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/533855/28900).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is that $x_{n}$ is a contractive sequence, such that $|x_{n+1} - x_{n} | \le C |x_{n} - x_{n-1}|$ for all $n \ge N$, $0 < C < 1$. You have $C = \frac{4}{9}$. Theorem : A contractive sequence is a Cauchy sequence, so it is enough to use the theorem.

But if you also want to prove it (you should try), in general it is the same step as you have so far, then use the hint from @julien with geometric series of ratio $C$.

Comment: I edited my post to show how far I've gotten-- what do I let $n_0$ equal so that for all $n>n_0, m>n_0$ I've got the full $\epsilon$ proof?

Comment: Wait: $$\frac{4}{5}(c-b)(1-(\frac{4}{9})^a) \leq \frac{4}{5}(c-b)$$

So let $n_0 = \epsilon * \frac{5}{4(c-b)}$ Correct?

Comment: for all $n$, $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}| \le C |x_{n+1} - x_{n}| \le C^2 |x_{n} - x_{n-1}| \le .... \le C^n |x_2 - x_1|$.  Now for $m > n$, $$ |x_{m} - x_{n}| \le |x_{m} - x_{m-1}| + |x_{m-1} - x_{m-2}| + ... + |x_{n+1} - x_n| \le .....  $$ , Evaluate the right side limit as $n$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$.

Comment: @user2899162 What my answer meant is that use the argument above, but your $\epsilon$ argument also suffice..